# "वैष्णवानां सहस्रेभ्यः शिवभक्तो विशिष्यते" from where this verse is taken from?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas, shloka, reference

What does this verse mean ? Also specify the exact location of the verse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Well this verse is present in both Śrī Liṅga Mahāpurāṅam and Śrī Saura Purāṅam.

---

### From Shri Linga Mahapurana :

[image]

> **अन्यभक्तसहस्रेभ्यो विष्णुभक्तो विशिष्यते ॥ विष्णुभक्तसहखेभ्यो रुद्रभक्तो विशिष्यते। रुद्रभक्कात्परतरो नास्ति लोके न संशयः ॥**
>
> ~ Linga Purana,  2.4.19b-20
>
> A devotee of Viṣṇu greater than thousands of other devotees. **A devotee
> of Rudra is far better than thousands of devotees of Viṣṇu. There is
> certainly no one greater than the devotee of Rudra in this world .**

---

### From Sri Saura Purana :

[image]

> **सूर्यवह्नीन्दुभक्तानामुत्तमो वैष्णवः परः ॥
> वैष्णवानां सहस्रेभ्यः शिवभक्तो विशिष्यते ।**
>
> ~ Sri Saura Purana, 11.8b-9a
>
> The worshiper of Vishnu is superior to the worshipers of Surya, Agni
> and Chandra. **A Shiva devotee is greater thousands of Vishnu
> devotee.**